# Rails refuses to store a value in a column named `authorization`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I've fought a few hours now to store a string in a database column in Rails.

I had to rename `authorization` to `transaction` so that Rails would store the value.

Why does Rails interfere while saving the value?

Example:

```
# Works
self.update_attribute(:transaction, result) rescue nil

# Does not work
self.update_attribute(:authorization, result) rescue nil
```

Comment: Does that class have belongs_to: :authorization

?

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci No. Authorization is a mere string. I also tried to prefix `authorization` which did not work either. It had to be something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your underlying database? **It might have "authorization" as a reserved word.**

See the generated sql and run it directly to your db. If it runs without problems, then my assumption is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Both mySQL and SQLserver use authorization as a reserved word.

So you'll just need to use the different word.

You could also use something close like 'authorized' or 'auth'.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try prefixing the column using the table name? For example:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_table.authorization = "new authorization"
WHERE id = 5
```